# how to normalise json from javascript in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, json

hello there i have this following j.s .. i am sending an array to my C# file  in r in json format

```
var r=['maths','computer','physics']

$.post("Global.aspx", { opt: "postpost", post: w.val(),tags:JSON.stringify(r)
}, function (d) {
});
```

but in c# i am getting this type of string:

> ["Maths""Computer""Physics"]

.
i want only the words maths,computer,physics not the [ sign and " sign .. please help me out

i have following c# code :

```
string[] _tags = Request.Form["tags"].ToString().Split(',');
                    string asd="";
                    foreach (string ad in _tags) {
                        asd += ad;

                    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact sample of the JSON data as  ["Maths""Computer""Physics"] is not valid JSON

Comment: i have only this and this is working ... but i am not getting the values maths physics computer separately in c#.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [JSON deserialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<string> list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<string>>(Request.Form["tags"]);
```

As pointed out, you've split your string on the `,` character leaving you with an array of:

```
[0] = "[\"Maths\""
[1] = "\"Computer\""
[2] = "\"Physics\"]"
```

Because JSON is a data type, those square brackets actually have functional meaning. They're not just useless extra characters. As such, you need to parse the data into a format you can actually work that.